# How to calculate a residue

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I have to calculate the sum of the residues at the $n$ m-order poles of a complex function
$$f(z)=\frac{z^{np-1}}{(az^n+b)^m}\ln z$$
when applying Residue Theorem for an integral. In this function, $m,n,p$ are positive integers, and $m>p$. $a,b\in\mathbf{R}$ are positive.

When using the limit equation for the residue of a m-order pole, I find it hard to get the high order derivative of this function.

Can anyone help me? Thanks for any guidance.

Comment: You could rewrite the expression as a Laurent Series in $a/b$

Answer (score 0):

You want the sum of the residues of the poles at radius $b/a$.  These lie on an annulus (with inner radius $b/(2a)$ and outer radius $2b/a$, say).  The positively oriented path integral along its inner boundary component encloses only the (potential) singularity at $z = 0$; call this $A$.  The positively oriented path integral along its outer boundary component encloses all $n$ of the $m^\text{th}$-order poles you are interested in and the singularity at $z = 0$; call this $B$.  The quantity you want is $\frac{1}{2\pi\mathrm{i}}(B - A)$.  However, $B$ is hard to calculate.  The negatively oriented path integral along the annulus's outer boundary component encloses only the (potential) singularity at $z = \infty$; call this integral $C$.  Note that $C = -B$, so the sum of residues you want is $\frac{1}{2\pi\mathrm{i}}(-C-A)$.

I observe the direct attack, computing residues of all $n$ of the $m^\text{th}$-order pole is hard.  Computing the residues of the singularities at $0$ and $\infty$ might be easier...

Comment: $ln z$ seems to have no residue at z=0…